# How to read in a semicolon delimited file in Pandas and normalize

Tags: python, pandas, csv, keyerror

I am trying to read in a wine quality dataset and normalize the data before I move on. I've read in the csv as semicolon delimited, but when I try to drop the target variable, quality, I'm getting an error that says that attribute isn't found in axis.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/whitewine.csv', delimiter="\s")
x = df.drop(['quality'], axis=0).values
```

**Error**:

> KeyError: "['quality'] not found in axis"

Comment: You are asking to drop a row where the index is "quality".  I suspect you want to drop the column labeled "quality", which would be `axis=1`.

Comment: That delimiter doesn't look like a semicolon, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/whitewine.csv', delimiter="\s")
X = df.drop(['quality'], axis=1)
y = df['quality']
```

Comment: my error is still the same, and I've changed back and forth between axis=1 and axis=0. I'm not sure how to move on from this point